# Pandas: How to extract data that has been grouped by

Tags: pandas, numpy, group-by

Here is an example code to demonstrate my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(10)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('xy'))

df

    x   y
0   9   4
1   0   1
2   9   0
3   1   8
4   9   0
... ... ...
95  0   4
96  6   4
97  9   8
98  0   7
99  1   7

groups = df.groupby(['x'])

groups.size()

x
0    11
1    12
2    15
3    13
4    14
5     5
6     6
7     9
8     5
9    10
dtype: int64
```

How can I access the x-values as a column and the aggregated y-values as a second column to plot x versus y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options.

1. Use `reset_index()`:

```
groups = df.groupby(['x']).size().reset_index(name='size')
```

2. Add `as_index=False` to `groupby`:

```
groups = df.groupby(['x'], as_index=False).size()
```

Output for both:

```
>>> groups
   x  size
0  0    16
1  1     9
2  2     9
3  3     5
4  4     7
5  5    10
6  6    10
7  7     7
8  8    12
9  9    15
```

Comment: simultaneous post, again ;)

Comment: Lol, I know! Racing! ️

Comment: @richardec: You were a few msec faster :-), is that true?

Comment: Well, sort of, but not exactly. :) We both answer lots of pandas questions here, and sometimes we both answer very similar answers at very similar times! :D

Comment: Which answer should I accept?

Comment: Whichever one you want, @len! There are lots of meta posts talking about it, but the tl;dr is to accept whatever one you feel like, for whatever reason :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use `as_index=False`:

```
groups = df.groupby(['x'], as_index=False)
out = groups.size()
out.plot(x='x', y='size')
```

If you only want to plot, you can also keep the x as index:

```
df.groupby(['x']).size().plot()
```

output:

```
   x  size
0  0    16
1  1     9
2  2     9
3  3     5
4  4     7
5  5    10
6  6    10
7  7     7
8  8    12
9  9    15
```

[image]

Comment: @BigBen yes, I just followed OP's initial code ;) I'll add it as well

Comment: Which answer should I accept? Because the were at nearly at the same time.

Comment: @len you can accept richardec's answer, it doesn't matter ;)